# Is there a way around in Cypress since we cant open new tabs?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress, browser-automation

I am testing an application where once I login a passcode generated(Passcode is generated everytime I login to the application) which is sent to my personal mail address. So I need to login into my email account copy the passcode from inbox and paste it in my application. Is it possible to do this in cypress.

Comment: No, this is a shortcoming in Cypress it cannot handle multiple tabs.

Comment: You can use a node email client linked to your account and to parse the passcode. Here are a few plugins for emails with cypress. https://docs.cypress.io/plugins/directory#Email